# How does the col function know which DataFrame we are referring to?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've always been a little confused by the `col` functions in Spark, both in Python and Scala. It seems that:

`df.col("zipcode")` in Scala is equivalent to

`df["zipcode"]` and `spark.sql.functions.col("zipcode")` in Python.

The last usage using https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.col is what confuses me. How does `spark.sql.functions.col` know which Python DataFrame we are referring to? We're just passing the name of the column.

Comment: it refers to the dataframe from which the column was selected. e.g. `df.select(F.col("zipcode"))` will refer to the column in `df`, while `df2.select(F.col("zipcode"))` will be for `df2`.

Comment: Is your confusion on the use of the function, or how it is implemented?

Comment: @Chris I think it's more the former...and maybe the latter will help me understand using it.

Comment: @mck So what if it's used just by itself, i.e. `F.col("zipcode")`? This seems to be a valid expression. Which DataFrame does it "refer to", and how does it know this?

Comment: @rishai it will be a standalone column not attached to any dataframe, but once it is attached to a select statement of a dataframe, it will refer to that dataframe.

Comment: @mck So there is no "data" associated with just `F.col("zipcode")` - and no transformations or actions can be applied to it?

Comment: @rishai you can transform it, e.g. you can call `F.substring(F.col("zipcode"), 1, 1)` to get the first letter of the zipcode column, but that wouldn't be materialized until it is attached to a dataframe. You cannot apply action, unless you associate it with a dataframe.

Comment: @mck Hmm, that's interesting. Upon further testing, it seems pyspark allows me to replace the `F.col('zipcode')` syntax with just the string literal `'zipcode'`, for what I've tested thus far.

Comment: @rishai in most situations, that is correct in pyspark. It's just a convenient feature to save you from typing `F.col`. The only place where it matters is in `when` and `otherwise` statements, where if you don't specify `F.col`, the string will be really interpreted as a string, not a column. Another scenario is when columns are compared. You can't compare strings and you must specify `F.col`.

Answer (score 5):

The *col* function refers to the dataframe which you are executing a transformation (select, join, and so on). And if you want to select one of your DataFrame columns, you should do the following:

```py
# you can import the col function directly
from pyspark.sql.functions import col 
 
# Imagine your df columns are: id, name, age

df.select(col("id"))
```

It means you are selecting the column "id" from the DataFrame "df". The select refers to your DataFrame object. You are passing the column object to the current DataFrame you are working with.